# what should be the approx build size for ipad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have developed an ipad app and want to send this build to the client.
But the size of that build is 206 MB.
Anyone please guide me.

Thanks.

Comment: If you have embedded 200MB media files in your IPA, then it's not really that big is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be of anysize, Its better to have a small size binary because users may not want to download a app which will take an entire day for download and installation. That said i know of a HD video app which has a binary size of 800 mb.

1. If there are unwanted images/videos
   then you can delete them to reduce
   the size of the app.
2. You can also keep low resolution
   images for pages not frequently
   shown.
3. You can use jpg instead of png images which tend to occupy less size with similar effect.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a limit to the size of the application that your client has put in place. If not, what's the problem? I don't think that Apple has any such limits in place. If you still wish to lower the size of the app, you're going to need to give us a little more information about the contents.